# Preventing Django templates base.py from resolving every possible foreign key relationship in an inline

Tags: django, django-templates

I am attempting to create an Inline on an existing Django Admin class, but am finding the page render times to be far too slow. I have identified the problem to lie in django templates/base.py "resolve" function, or in the subsequent render function (Django 2.1). It would seem all my "Track" objects are being loaded for all forms in the line in all cases.

How can I increase the performance of this function by changing my code? Should I restructure the Recording-->Tracklist-->TracklistTrack-->Track relationship? Could I cache my model objects somehow? Is using a .through model in an inline unwise?

To begin finding the problem, I started using a profiler. When running a timer on the code, the profiler in question causes negligible slowdown.

I can see that the vast majority of my 22s function call is as follows:

ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)

```
  123    0.001    0.000   18.194    0.148 django/forms/widgets.py:232(_render)
  123    0.002    0.000   18.190    0.148 django/forms/renderers.py:29(render)
```

`848104    1.037    0.000    3.867    0.000 django/template/base.py:668(resolve)`

I looked at stack overflow posts which suggested overriding both "queryset" and "formfield_for_db". When printing context in the django functions, I can see that all of my Tracks are being piped through base.py resolve, and presumably, this is the problem.

The new inline looks like this:

````
    model = Tracklist.tracks.through

    readonly_fields = ('tracklist', 'recording')
    fields = ('track', 'timestamp', 'order')

    @silk_profile(name='Slow Inline')
    def formfield_for_dbfield(self, db_field, **kwargs):
        formfield = super(TracklistInline, self).formfield_for_dbfield(db_field, **kwargs)
        if db_field.name in ['track', 'tracklist', 'recording']:
            # dirty trick so queryset is evaluated and cached in .choices
            formfield.choices = formfield.choices
        return formfield

    def queryset(self, request):
        return super(MyAdmin, self).queryset(request).select_related(
            'track').select_related('tracklist').select_related('recording')```

Where Tracklist looks like this:

```class Tracklist(Timestamped, models.Model):
    """Tracklist is a collection of tracks, owned by a recording

              1                     0...1
    Recording   -------------------       Tracklist

              1                     0...*
    Tracklist   -------------------       Track"""
    tracks = models.ManyToManyField(
        Track, through="TracklistTrack", blank=True)
    recording = models.OneToOneField(
        Recording, related_name='tracklist', null=True, blank=True,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)```

and tracklist_track, my customised join table, looks like this:

```class TracklistTrack(models.Model):
    """Stores ordering for a Tracklist/Track relationship"""
    class Meta:
        indexes = [
            models.Index(fields=['recording']),
        ]

    tracklist = models.ForeignKey(Tracklist, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    recording = models.ForeignKey(
        Recording, related_name='tracklistsTrack',
        null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    track = models.ForeignKey(Track, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    timestamp = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    order = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)```

(A Track is a simple model with two charfields only, but a Recording is a bit of a monster)
````

Answer (score 0):

For anyone trawling stack overflow, I fixed this very simply with django 2.0's autocomplete field:

```
class TracklistInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Tracklist.tracks.through

    list_display = ('recording', 'timestamp', 'order')
    autocomplete_fields = ('track',)
    exclude = ('tracklist',)
    extra = 0

@admin.register(Track)
class TrackAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = TrackForm
    ordering = ['title']
    search_fields = ('artist', 'title')
    list_display = ('artist', 'title',)
    exclude = ('modified',)
```